# Livewire encountered corrupt data when trying to hydrate the component

Tags: laravel-livewire

**Livewire encountered corrupt data when trying to hydrate the [sanction-letter] component. Ensure that the [name, id, data] of the Livewire component wasn't tampered with between requests**

I am not understanding how to debug this issue and why this issue is coming?

tried different solution form google but nothing helped me

Answer (score 0):

This happens when your template is using magic functions and loads additional data. E.g.

```
$this->post->owner->full_name;
```

Avoid loading additional data in your template.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this github issue: https://github.com/livewire/livewire/issues/821

You get this error when the data returned from the frontend isn't equal to the backend. This is designed as protective layer against users messing with the request. However, sometimes PHP to JS and back to PHP causes some issues, that can trigger this error without intention. The most common one is that JS reorders associative arrays with numeric keys.

As stated in the github issue:

```php
public $array = [
    'foo' => 'bar',
    '123' => 500,
]
```

gets converted to

```php
public $array = [
    '123' => 500,
    'foo' => 'bar',
]
```

It can be anything, really, as I personally experienced a situation where a value (`-0,2`) got rounded to `-0`, and JS converted it to `0`, causing this error.